# Deeply inject different implementation at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

How can I "deeply inject" different implementations at runtime? For example, suppose that I have a `MyInterface` interface that has multiple implementations. The interface is used some levels deep into the application hierarchy, and I want to select the right implementation at a higher level.

E.g. in this example, I have an `Controller` that takes in an `impl` parameter, and then has a call chain from `Controller->Service2->Service1->MyInterface`. Based on the `impl` passed in to the controller, we need to use a different `MyInterface`.

```
interface MyInterface {
    public void do();
}

@Component
class Impl1 implements MyInterface { /* */ }

@Component
class Impl2 implements MyInterface { /* */ }

@Component
class Service1 {
    private MyInterface myInt;

    public void do() {
        this.myInt.do();
    }
}

@Component
class Service2 {
    private Service1 service1;

    public void do() {
        this.service1.do();
    }
}

@Component
class Controller {
    private Service2 service2;

    public void do(String impl /* "impl1" or "impl2" */) {
        // TODO: How to "inject" the right implementation here based on `impl`?
        this.service2.do();
    }
}
```

Now in this contrived example, I could create a `MyInterfaceRegistry` which `Service1` depends on, and then drill down `impl` through the stack. However, in real-world scenarios we might be using `MyInterface` in many different places and many layers deep. The registry approach would then require us to drill down the `impl` through all layers of the application, which I want to avoid.

I'm looking for something in this spirit:

```
@Component
class Controller {
    private Provider<Service2> service2Provider;
    private MyInterfaceRegistry myInterfaceRegistry;

    public void do(String impl /* "impl1" or "impl2" */) {
        // "bind" the implementation here, such that `Service1` will use the bound provider without needing to drill down parameters
        Service2 service2 = service2Provider
            .bind(MyInterface, myInterfaceRegistry.get(impl))
            .get();
        service2.do();
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this with Spring Boot?

Comment: use `ApplicationContext.getBean(yourImplClassOrQualifiedName)`

Comment: How would that work? Mind that I want to make the selection in the `Controller`, without explicitly passing anything down to the services. I don't think calling `ApplicationContext.getBean` at that level does anything useful for me here, nor will it help me in `Service1` without drilling down arguments.

Comment: Well it allows you to get implementation instance based on some input argument you were looking for, no? It is literally your `MyInterfaceRegistry`

Comment: Ok, but that's not the problem we're trying to solve, The problem we're trying to solve is that we want to _select_ the implementation in `Controller`, but _use_ it in `Service1`, without passing parameters down. I.e. the `.bind` bit at the end of my question.

Comment: Putting aside that this is a bad design choice IMO - Having your services lets say, `RequestScoped` you can get `service2Provider` in controller, set the correct implementation (it is just a holder) and down the line again use `service2Provider` to get it back. It will not work with singletons as long as you plan to have more that 1 request the time. (I just noticed that Controller is a Component thus maybe it is not about web)

Comment: So the long story short, use `Provider<Service2> service2Provider` in your `Controller` and `Service1` with to bean scopes and concurency.

Comment: It's just IoC, I don't think there's anything wrong with that ;) Regardless, `RequestScoped` does point me in a good direction. As you've correctly noticed (sharp eye), the "real world" situation isn't about web, but I can create a custom Scope for that. The main takeaway is that I can have a stateful `Provider` bean that's `@Scope`d to my "request", which then allows me to set the value at the entry point, and use it throughout the request handling. Thanks!

Comment: The fact, that *It's just IoC* means only that it is doable one way or another. Now why it is bad design choice - uneeded flow complexity added to the code which leads to the situation where you have to analise what happened X layers prior the frame in which NPE happened to understand why it did. All in all, it will work until it stops - and then the price raises. Take look on many legacy systems. We can all agree that they all work just fine - until they stop. And then it is sometimes cheeper to write everything from the scrach that try to fix black magic code :) Food for thought. Good luck.

Comment: And yes, having statefull components is kind of must in here. Stateless are simpler to maintain :

Comment: Yeap, the challenge here is that the real world situation is quite a bit more complex than the example here. I'm dealing with a situation where high in the call chain a strategy is selected, which the "middle layer" is agnostic to, and then far down the call chain we need to select the right implementations. The surface area of all of this is quite large, passing the strategy down manually adds its own complexity (+ lots of noise). From a theoretical perspective I want to create/select/fork an IoC container at the top of the request, which is feasible in other frameworks, ... (cont)

Comment: ... but seems to go against the design principles of spring. So now I'm stuck to choose between 2 suboptimal situations: either I make ALL of the code aware of the strategy, which adds complexity everywhere but is explicit, or I use a stateful approach, which adds complexity in just one place but is implicit. Of course, the right trade-off here is massively influenced by the particularities of the real-world application, which is not relevant for the broader SO audience, but I'm leaning towards the stateful approach being the lesser evil for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided `impl` value is runtime data, supplied to the Controller after it and its whole object graph have long been constructed. This means that you can't *inject* different `MyInterface` implementations based on this runtime condition. But even if you could, it is my opinion that you should strive to have a object graphs that are fixed in structure; you do not switch injected implementations during the lifetime of the application; that only complicated things. This is related to the argument I made [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/) about injecting *runtime data* into your application components.

But since injecting different dependencies is not a feasible option, there are two alternatives left:

#### Option 1: Pushing `impl` down the call graph

You pass on the `impl` runtime data down the call graph to `Service1` and let `Service1` decide which implementation to call; assuming that you now inject both `MyInterface` implementations into `Service1`'s constructor.

```java
@Component
class Service1 {
    private MyInterface impl1;
    private MyInterface impl2;

    public void do(String impl) {
        if (impl == "impl1")
            this.impl1.do();
        else
            this.impl2.do();
    }
}

@Component
class Service2 {
    private Service1 service1;

    public void do(String impl) {
        this.service1.do(impl);
    }
}

@Component
class Controller {
    public void do(String impl) {
        service2.do(impl);
    }
}
```

Downside of this approach is that this can cause a snowball effect throughout the application depending on where `MyInterface` is used. When `MyInterface` is an implementation detail for a given service it would cause that service to leak implementation details because it now requires its abstraction to be changed so that `impl` can be supplied to it. There is, therefore, another option to consider:

### Supply `impl` to the rest of the graph through a 'context provider'.

You can create and inject an `ImplContext` service into `Controller` that allows you to set the specific `impl` for the given context (current web request). Instead of injecting either `Impl1` or `Impl2` into `Service1` you can now inject a 'context-based MyInterface proxy' class that depends on `Impl1`, `Impl2`, *and* `ImplContext`. Based on the choice made in the `Controller`, it can either call `Impl1` or `Impl2.

Here's an example:

```java
interface ImplContext
{
    String Impl { get; set; }
}

class ClosureImplContext implements ImplContext
{
    public String Impl { get; set; }
}

@Component class Controller {
    private ImplContext context;

    public void do(String impl) {
        this.context.Impl = impl;
        service2.do();
    }
}

@Component class ContextBasedInterfaceProxy implements MyInterface {
    private MyInterface impl1;
    private MyInterface impl2;
    private ImplContext context;

    public void do() {
        this.GetImplemtentation().do();
    }

    private MyInterface GetImplementation() {
        if (this.context.Impl == "impl1") return this.impl1;
        return this.impl2;
    }
}
```

To make it easier to create a mental model, this is what it would look like if you would construct the object graph by hand:

```java
// ClosureImplContext is shared within the context of a single controller
var context = new ClosureImplContext();
new Controller(
    new Service2(
        new Service1(
            new ContextBasedInterfaceProxy(
                new Impl1(),
                new Impl2(),
                context))));
```

The advantage of this approach is that `Service2` and `Service1` will be oblivious to the existing of the switching between implementations. This prevents leaking implementation details throughout the object graph and prevents cascading changes to the graph. The downside is that a contextual service needs to be used that `Controller` needs to know of.

Notice how, with this approach, `ContextBasedInterfaceProxy` switches between the two implementations, but it always gets both implementations injected into it. This means that the whole object graph for `Controller` will never change, but only when the `Controller` is used, will the decisions be made to either call `Impl1` or `Impl2`.